# Long and short touches on a Button should give different results

Tags: android, multithreading, android-button

I need the `Button` to change the layout when I hold it down for 3 seconds, but when I push once quickly it should just play a sound.

In the code below the sound comes no matter what (because that's okay in this case).

My problem is that it **only** changes page the very first time you use the `Button` whether it's held down (to change layout) or just a short click (only to play sound). 
So if I hold down button and it changes layout, but then I go back it won't work a second time.  Also, if a short touch is used to play the sound I can't hold the button down to change layout.

```
final Button b1pad1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1pad1);
b1pad1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(PhotosActivity.this, R.raw.sub);
            mp.start();
            holdTimer = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        int timer = 0;
                        while (timer<3000) {
                            sleep(100); 
                            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { 
                                //checks whether you lifted your finger before 
                                //the 3 seconds.
                                breaked = "no"; 
                                //"no" means "don't change layout"
                                changetobrowser(b1pad1, breaked);
                                break;    
                            }
                            timer = timer + 100;
                        }
                        if (breaked.equals("")){
                            breaked = "go"; //go means "change the layout"
                            changetobrowser(b1pad1,breaked);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            holdTimer.start();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // End
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
});

public void  changetobrowser(Button but, String breaked) {
    if (breaked.equals("go")){
        Intent browseIntent = new Intent(PhotosActivity.this, BrowseScreen.class);
        startActivity(browseIntent); 
    } else {
    }
}
```

What could the problem be? And is this even the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Holy hell you have a lot of stuff wrong here. Right away I can tell you that this will never work `if (breaked == "go")`. That's not how you compare strings in Java.

Comment: actually that part works, when I debug? but it should be equals. yeah. changing it right away.

Comment: I edited the post to improve readability, as well as making future edits easier.  Just need someone to accept the edit for me.

Comment: Thanks :) really can't figure this one out.

Comment: "multithreading" and "UI" should seldom go together .. use the UI-thread and background workers. Adding manual Threads generally just complicates things. And spawning a new thread-per-UI-action should be a red flag.

Comment: Yeah, of course. I'll delete the manual thread then. How do I use the UI-thread? //noob here.

Comment: Just as a general suggestion, I would recommend you avoid putting too much code inside of a single case-statement.  Your first case should really be calling a function.  That alone would dramatically improve how others are able to read the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using an `OnLongClickListener`? It's invoked when a `View` has been clicked and held for a short while. For other cases, you can use a simple `OnClickListener`, which is invoked upon press.

More information here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

Comment: I think this is just what I need! That would eliminate the need for timers etc. I'll take a look at it. thanks! (og du er dansk!)

Comment: AMAZING! That was the easiest solution. Thank you!

Comment: Great! You can accept the answer to close this question :-) (jeps, det er jeg!)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is totally wrong (IMO of course).

Instead of using a `Thread` to keep track of time you can use the `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Also I suggest you to do some reading on the `onTouch()` method so you can have a better understanding on how it works. Especially the `MotionEvent` event.

Comment: I know. I'm probably all wrong. Haven't worked much with this stuff before. But I'll take a look at the things you've mentioned.

Comment: Can't really figure out how System.currentTimeMillis() should be used for checking if the user is holding the button down for 3 seconds?

Comment: You would read the current time and store it somewhere, then keep checking the stored time against the current time until `if( curTime - storedTime > 3000){ // code to execute after three seconds }`